# TeX should be supported on E&R, like on Math.SE, et. al.

Tags: bug, status-completed, tex

Want (La)TeX.  'nuff said.

e.g. [Ugly single-line equations](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/getting-higher-power-output-by-using-more-resistors/8014#8014)

The problem is still here, two months later.  I could add some more examples which I've read and written in the meantime, but it seems blatantly obvious that a site for engineers should have better markup for equations than plan text.  In fact, it's so obvious that I'm altering the tags on this question to mark it as a bug.  The feature exists, it's just not activated, and it's a bug that this site doesn't have [La]TeX.

Test: $\TeX$

Comment: Where do I sign up?

Comment: @tyblu - Right here, just upvote this question.

Comment: Note that $\TeX$ won't work. You have to use `\$\TeX\$`, which looks like \$\TeX\$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have enabled LaTeX on E&R based on this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed.  The ability to write questions and answers with good-looking equations is essential to the professionalism of this site.

This is not a new problem, it's been discussed at the following sites, and probably on others:

- [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57931/)
- [meta.mathoverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/637/)
- [meta.math.stackexchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/)
- [meta.tex.stackexchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/)
- [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129/) (For generic sites)

(Links point to relevant discussions on the named sites.)

Answer (score 0):

$$R1 \parallel R2 = \frac{R_{1}R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}$$

$$P = IV = I^{2}R = \frac{V^{2}}{R}$$